# How to dynamically set the immediate property in watch？

Tags: vue.js

These components may be used in different places, some need the immediate attribute in the watch, some do not need

Boolean values related to variables are invalid

```
watch:{
        color:{
          handler () {
            let rgba = this.color.rgba;
            let currentColor = rgba.a === 1 ? this.color.hex : `rgba(${rgba.r},${rgba.g},${rgba.b},${rgba.a})`;
            this.submit('color',this.now,currentColor)
          },
          immediate: !(this.now==="standard")

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try set the `watch` property on your vue instance once you have the value you want then wrote something like this:

```
//get info for my immediate value then instantiate a watcher like this:
this.$watch('$data.color', this.handler, { deep: true })
or 
this....{deep: false}
```

Comment: But The immediate attribute is a variable, not a constant,which I want.